# Sonata approve functionality

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I've an Entity that contains comments. It has a very simple structure

```
sent_at | DateTime
comment_author | Text
comment_text | Text
approved_at | DateTime (null when the comments is inserted)
```

I've set up sonata and I can now manage comments.

The "Edit" page it has a group of drop down to set the date and the time for the field `approved_at` What I would like to do is to have a check box in the "Edit" page that if checked save the current date&time in `approved_at`

How can I do this  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonataAdminBundle provides 3 `Saving hooks`. Straight from documentation:

```
new object : prePersist($object) / postPersist($object)
edited object : preUpdate($object) / postUpdate($object)
deleted object : preRemove($object) / postRemove($object)
```

So, the one you're interested with, is `preUpdate()`

In order to achieve what you want, you have to add new `non-mapped` field to your form:

```
 // This is needed to check the checkbox if the message has been already approved
 $approved = false;

 $review = $this->getSubject();

 if ($review->getApprovedAt()) {
    $approved = true;
 }

 [..]

 $builder->add('approve', 'checkbox',
     array(
          // We don't need this as property in our entity.
          'mapped' => false,
          // The field should not be required, so that you can skip approving specific comment at the time
          'required' => false,
          'data' => $approved
     )
 );
```

Now, all you have to do is read the value on update and set the datetime if checked:

```
 public function preUpdate($object) {
      /* @var $isApproved boolean */
      $isApproved = $this->getForm()->get('approve')->getData();

      if( $isApproved ) {
          $object->setApprovedAt( new \DateTime('now') );
      }
 }
```

And this should do the trick. The chapter from documentation - [here.](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/saving_hooks.html)

Comment: Update works but when I edit and already approved comment the checkbox is not checked. How do I solve this ?

Comment: Since you're using a non-mapped field `approve` you have to dynamically assign the value to `true` or `false`. One way would be to check if `approved_at` is not empty (then you would check the field) - otherwise, you leave it like it is now (not checked)

Comment: Ok, but how ? I don't know Sonata. Is there a `postRead` event or something where I can change the data passed to the form.

Comment: In your `configureFormFields` method you can call `$this->getSubject()`. This would return instance of your class (all fields would be nullable when creating new record). After you obtain your class reference, you can simply check for `->getApprovedAt()`